# Validating the JWT token from the Identity server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I made an identity server 4 with .net CORE api and a Angular SPA as a client.
I have a successfully login on the /connect/token endpoint of the identity server.
Each call that i will make to the API will be with this token in the header (to be [Authorized]).
My question is : If someone gets my token and will put that in the request headers, he can impersonate me. How can i check in the token if the one who is using it is the real owner?
Is there any endpoint on the Identity Server 4 that will do that for me?
I also want to know and understand the concept.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe you are saying if there is a man in middle attack. I think there are ways to solve it with referer token and request validation token. I think it will be interesting to find the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, i thought about MITM attack